# memfd_secret(): how is it supposed to work?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

`memfd_secret()` was merged in the kernel, but I do not see  the real security benefit of it. I mean, this has the idea of avoiding sideline attacks, but this is like when the car keys are locked and nobody knows where they are.

AFAIK, the page given to the application simply is not mapped when in kernel mode, but this cant be used to isolate a virus, or whatever of the kernel itself.

How is it supposed to be safer to isolate a range of memory of the kernel?

Could someone provide a code example showing how this protects of spectre or like that?

**Update**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while(true) {
        int rc = fork();
        if(rc == -1) {
            perror("fork error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is by definition safer by making the memory inaccessible to any other process including the kernel. What is your specific doubt about that? Please ask a clearer and more specific question (the "car keys" analogy does not help as it is not clear how that relates).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memfd_secret()` allows a user-space process to have a "secret" memory area. In this context, "secret" means that other processes cannot have access to that memory area (not even the kernel itself, or at least not by accident).

This syscall allows a process to store confidential information (like a password or a private key) in a more secure way, because it's harder for a malware to access that secret memory area. This syscall should also protect from vulnerabilities like Spectre, because the secret memory area is uncached; and should also protect (albeit not completely, but at least partially) from kernel bugs, since the kernel has no access to that memory area.

In order to use this syscall (that will be available in Linux 5.14), you first make a call to `memfd_secret()` in order to obtain a file descriptor; then you make a call to `ftruncate()` in order to choose the size of the secret memory region; and finally you use `mmap()` in order to map the secret memory, so you can access it via pointers as usual.

Other details are available [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/865256).

EDIT: unfortunately, the "uncached" feature that made `memfd_secret()` less vulnerable to attacks like Spectre has been removed because there was a concern for perfomance.

EDIT 2: additional details about why secret memory areas obtained with `memfd_secret()` makes programs safer ([source](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/1431059/), slightly modified by me for clearness):

- Enhanced protection (in conjunction with all the other in-kernel
  attack prevention systems) against [ROP attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming). Secret memory makes "simple"
  ROP insufficient to perform exfiltration, which increases the required
  complexity of the attack. Along with other protections like the kernel
  stack size limit and address space layout randomization which make finding
  gadgets is really hard, absence of any in-kernel primitive for accessing
  secret memory means the one gadget ROP attack can't work. Since the only
  way to access secret memory is to reconstruct the missing mapping entry,
  the attacker has to recover the physical page and insert a PTE pointing to
  it in the kernel and then retrieve the contents.  That takes at least three
  gadgets which is a level of difficulty beyond most standard attacks.
- Prevent cross-process secret user-space memory exposures. Once the secret
  memory is allocated, the user can't accidentally pass it into the kernel to
  be transmitted somewhere. The secret memory pages cannot be accessed via the
  direct map and they are disallowed in GUP.
- Harden against exploited kernel flaws. In order to access secret memory, a
  kernel-side attack would need to either walk the page tables and create new
  ones, or spawn a new privileged user-space process to perform secrets
  exfiltration using ptrace.

EDIT 3: just a note that I think may be relevant: secret memory areas can be accessed by child processes created using `fork()`, so one must be cautious. At least, using flag `O_CLOEXEC` (passed to `memfd_secret()`), the process will not make the secret memory available to processes created with `execve()`.

Comment: I'm not sure you answered the question. He doesn't want to know how to use it, but how the kernel can create a memory area that it can't access itself? Isn't the `memfd` driver in the kernel?

Comment: Then the feature removed, render this method less util or useless?

Comment: @Barmar OP said `Could someone provide a code example?`, I think they meant how could possibly be used in a C program. `memfd` already is in the kernel, but doesn't support secret memory areas yet (these can only be obtained with the `memfd_secret()` syscall that will make it in Linux 5.14).

Comment: @Barmar, thats the idea

Comment: @avelardo Well, while I'm not personally happy about that choice, the possibility of stealing memory information from those secret areas should be very low, even without the uncached feature.

Comment: @LucaPolito, hum, the idea is syscall ran by any other process (root included) will not cause the kernel to map these RAM, then it cannot read or write from it. It can only unmap it.

Comment: @avelardo I've added additional reasons why secret memory enhances programs' safety.

Comment: @LucaPolito, thanks for the great info, the last edit is intriguing, do you have more info why?, this is more or less risk, because fork() must be managed to avoid errors, think of the edit done, perhaps this can be misused to bypass fork().

Comment: @avelardo Since `memfd_secret()` returns a file descriptor (like `open()`, `socket()`, etc.) they probably decided that this file descriptor will be inherited by children (just like other file descriptors), or maybe it would have been complicated to avoid that. Anyway, probably (like other file descriptors) if you create the memory area *after* forking, the children will not have access to it.

Comment: @LucaPolito, thanks its a good info, and good to know, very kind.